# Print one byte signed number with hexdump

Tags: text-formatting, hexdump

I want to read `/dev/input/mice` with hexdump. Format is described at [here at StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11451618/how-do-you-read-the-mouse-button-state-from-dev-input-mice). What I need is to read one byte (flags), print it in hex format, then read two bytes (x and y move offset) and print each in signed decimal format.

I use *hexdump from util-linux 2.28* on Arch Linux.

The best I was able to put together is

```
 hexdump /dev/input/mice -e '/1 "%03x" 2/1 " %03d" /0 "\n"'
```

The format string:

1. `/1 "%03x"` reads one byte and prints it as hex number
2. `2/1 " %03d"` reads one byte and prints it as signed decimal integer, repeats two times
3. `/0 "\n"` reads zero bytes and prints end of line

The problem is that for value 0xFF the `%d` specifier prints 255 instead of -1. The format is taken from C, which extends the width properly, so how to force this proper width extension here?

Comment: Your example works for me, using `hexdump` from bsdmainutils (tried 9.0.3 and 9.0.5ubuntu).  Which version are you using?

Comment: @JigglyNaga version added to question

Comment: On Debian Jessie, it returns -1; on CentOS it returns 255.  On CentOS `hexdump` comes from util-linux.  On Debian it comes from bsdmainutils.  There seems to be an incompatibility between the two versions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in that implementation of `hexdump`.

The function responsible is

```
print(struct hexdump_pr *pr, unsigned char *bp)
```

in [`hexdump-display.c`](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/utils/util-linux/util-linux.git/tree/text-utils/hexdump-display.c?id=098ab0778f5a46ab4519c8404fd4ba8ec137368b#n147). It copies the correct number of bytes into a suitable variable, so that sign-extending can happen when passing the value to `printf()`.  But for single bytes, it doesn't bother - it just dereferences the pointer, which was to an *unsigned* char.

```
case F_INT:
        {
        short sval; /* int16_t */
        int ival;   /* int32_t */
        long long Lval; /* int64_t, int64_t */

        switch(pr->bcnt) {
        case 1:
            printf(pr->fmt, (unsigned long long) *bp);
            break;
        case 2:
            memmove(&sval, bp, sizeof(sval));
            printf(pr->fmt, (unsigned long long) sval);
            break;
```

To fix it, patch the function to use the same "copy to local variable" approach:

```
--- text-utils/hexdump-display.c.orig   2015-10-05 15:18:43.458759033 +0100
+++ text-utils/hexdump-display.c        2016-08-19 14:58:35.507705329 +0100
@@ -146,13 +146,15 @@
            }
        case F_INT:
            {
+               char cval;      /* int8_t */
                short sval;     /* int16_t */
                int ival;       /* int32_t */
                long long Lval; /* int64_t, int64_t */

                switch(pr->bcnt) {
                case 1:
-                       printf(pr->fmt, (unsigned long long) *bp);
+                       memmove(&cval, bp, sizeof(cval));
+                       printf(pr->fmt, (unsigned long long) cval);
                        break;
                case 2:
                        memmove(&sval, bp, sizeof(sval));
```